# Winsock connection does not work

Tags: delphi, winsock

I am using Delphi 2007. In my Delphi application I need to send a string via a port and IP and the receiver has to send me an answer.

I have created this code but I am not sure if I am really doing things correctly, because I receive no answer:

```
 procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
 var port:integer;
 begin
  port:=StrToInt(edit4.text);
  ClientSocket1.Port:=21000;
  ClientSocket1.Host:=Edit3.text;
  ClientSocket1.ClientType:=ctNonBlocking;
  ClientSocket1.Active:=true;
  ClientSocket1.Connect.
 end;    

 procedure TForm1.ClientSocket1Connect(Sender: TObject;  Socket:CustomWinSocket); 
 begin
  Checkbox1.Checked:=true;
  Edit1.Text:=Socket.LocalAddress;
  Edit2.Text:=Socket.LocalHost;
  Memo2.Lines.Clear;
  Edit5.Text:='STX ~ JR | ETX';
 end;

 procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
 begin
  if ClientSocket1.Active then
   ClientSocket1.Socket.SendText(Edit5.text)
  else
   Memo1.Lines.Add('Not working');
 end;

 procedure TForm1.ClientSocket1Read(Sender: TObject; Socket: CustomWinSocket);
 begin
  Memo2.Lines.Add(Socket.ReceiveText);
 end;
```

How can I be sure I am still connected before clicking second button? (The one who sends the data).

Sorry for my bad English and apologies if I am breaking any rule.

Comment: Side note, TClient/TServersocket are really old components and not updated. Better take a look at the [Indy component suite](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Download/Files/Indy10.EN.aspx).

Comment: And always mention your delphi version.

Comment: This looks suspicious: `Edit5.Text:='Chr($H2) + Chr($H7E) + "JR" + Chr($H7C) + Chr($H3)';` and `ClientSocket1.Socket.SendText(Edit5.text)`. Does the receiver really expect that literal string including all `Chr`'s, parens, plusses, double quotes etc. or does it actually expect six characters `#$02 + #$7E + 'J' + 'R' + #$7C + #$03`? Hexadecimal notation in Delphi uses only `$`, no `H`. The character `#` denotes a character value.

Comment: Yeah, well, thats the last thing I tried, I've also tried that strng being "STX ~ JR | ETX"

I am using Delphi 2007 by the way

Comment: Please edit your question with exact copy - paste of what you have tried.

Comment: That string still doesn't look right. It will send an 'S' followed by a 'T' followed by an 'X' etc. I am sure that is not what you mean. Please try Edit5.Text := #$02 + #$7E + 'J' + 'R' + #$7C + #$03 as suggested by Tom BrunBerg

Comment: Or more simply Edit5.Text := #02 + '~JR|' + #03

Answer (score 0):

> How can I be sure I am still connected before clicking second button? (The one who sends the data).

In your code you set `CheckBox1.Checked := true` when ClientSocket1 is connected.
So you can set  the same check box to false when disconected using `ClientSocket1.OnDisconnect` event.
ClientSocket1Disconnect is fired automatically when connection is broken.

```
procedure TForm1.ClientSocket1Disconnect(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
begin
  Checkbox1.Checked:=false;
end;
```

Now you may use CheckBox1 as an indicator if`ClientSocket1` is connected or not.